# Cast Derived to Base dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries. How I can assign DerivedClass dictionary to DerivedClass dictionary ?

Below code not worrking?

How can I change it?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void DoWork() { }
    public int WorkField;
    public int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new void DoWork() { }
    public new int WorkField;
    public new int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var derivedclass = new Dictionary<string, DerivedClass>();
        var baseClass = new Dictionary<string, BaseClass>();

        Dictionary<string, BaseClass> AAA = derivedclass;


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. `Dictionary<string, DerivedClass>` does not inherit from `Dictionary<string, BaseClass>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not covariant on `TValue`. Pretty much the best you can do is create a new dictionary from your original one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast the dictionary directly, but you can create a new dictionary, something like this will work:

```
Dictionary<string, BaseClass> AAA = 
    derivedclass.ToDictionary(
        k => k.Key, 
        v => (BaseClass)v.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  `Dictionary` (along with all classes in C#) are invariant with respect their generic arguments.

And even if C# worked to support generic type variance on classes (rather than just interfaces and delegates) `Dictionary` is conceptually not invariant with respect to the type of the value of the dictionary.  You can add new values to a dictionary, so if you could cast a `Dictionary<int, Tiger>` to a `Dictionary<int, Animal>` then you could put a `Chicken` in that dictionary of tigers, and we all know how well that would end.

If you had an `IReadOnlyDictionary` interface it could potentially be covariant with respect to the type of the value, although the .NET implementation isn't.